# Improve WITH CTE Query Optimization SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have a query with multiple queries in it that get tied together at the end. I am working through optimizing it, to get it to run faster. I was using 3 queries that created tables and inserted records into them. I looked at my execution plan and saw that one of them was eating up 100% of the cost relative to the batch, so I changed it to the form of `;WITH CTE AS()` and that brought it's cost down to 64% of the batch.

Right now I see that the `Hash Match (Aggreagate)` inside of this query represents 41% of the cost of this query. From the estimated plan it also says that `Missing Index (Impact 71.7682): CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX....` Is this something that can be done inside of the `WITH` query?

Here is the part that I am trying to make more efficient

```
;WITH ERCNT AS (
    SELECT A.MRN
    , A.VISIT_ID
    , A.VISIT_DATE
    , COUNT(B.VISIT_ID) AS VISIT_COUNT

    FROM 
    (
    SELECT MED_REC_NO AS MRN, vst_start_dtime AS VISIT_DATE, PT_NO AS VISIT_ID
    FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V
    WHERE
    ((
        Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
        AND Adm_Source NOT IN 
            (
            'RP'
            )
        )
        OR pt_type = 'E')
    AND vst_start_dtime >= @SD 
    AND vst_start_dtime < @ED
    )A

    LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT MED_REC_NO AS MRN, VST_START_DTIME AS VISIT_DATE, PT_NO AS VISIT_ID
    FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V
    WHERE
    ((
        Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
        AND Adm_Source NOT IN
            (
            'RP'
            )
        )
        OR pt_type = 'E')
    AND vst_start_dtime >= @SD 
    AND vst_start_dtime < @ED
)B
ON A.MRN = B.MRN
AND A.VISIT_DATE > B.VISIT_DATE
--AND A.VISIT_DATE < B.VISIT_DATE

GROUP BY A.MRN, A.VISIT_ID, A.VISIT_DATE
)
```

If I need to provide additional information please let me know.

Thank you,

Comment: Here are a few [Links](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) that might [Help](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: Do you have any control over those codes? It would be nice if they were INT values.

Comment: sigh...no control I'm just a `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is the left join between A and B. I assume you cannot create the index suggested by query engine. What about using table variable to store the result of the sub-query and have the index there? You can then use that table in your CTE. Following pseudo-code should give you the idea:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
(
  MRN ???, VISIT_DATE ???, visit_id ???, PRIMARY KEY(MRN, VISIT_DATE)
)

INSERT INTO @tmp
    SELECT MED_REC_NO AS MRN, vst_start_dtime AS VISIT_DATE, PT_NO AS VISIT_ID
    FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V
    WHERE
    ((
        Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
        AND Adm_Source NOT IN 
            (
            'RP'
            )
        )
        OR pt_type = 'E')
    AND vst_start_dtime >= @SD 
    AND vst_start_dtime < @ED

;WITH ERCNT AS (
    SELECT A.MRN
    , A.VISIT_ID
    , A.VISIT_DATE
    , COUNT(B.VISIT_ID) AS VISIT_COUNT

FROM @tmp A
LEFT JOIN @tmp B
ON A.MRN = B.MRN
AND A.VISIT_DATE > B.VISIT_DATE
GROUP BY A.MRN, A.VISIT_ID, A.VISIT_DATE
)
```

Comment: that's an interesting idea I'll give that a whack and see what happens

Comment: Why use a table-variable? IMHO an actual temp-table would work as well and you'd never have to worry about datatypes (assuming you use the `SELECT INTO` approach). Also, #temp tables allows for easier indexing and probably most important: it has statistics, something badly lacking with table-variables.

Comment: I got a primary key constraint error for a datetime so I am taking the visit_date out of the primary key argument for now

Comment: @deroby I will give that a whack too, I thought about using the form of the CTE because it seems to me that with my data it tends to run a bit faster, but I have not tried using the select into for this portion yet so I will try that as well

Comment: So far this reduces my query from 7:16 minutes down to 1:46 minutes, I will have to try the other mentioned possible solutions before I check off an answer but so far this one is working like butta

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator if the PK fails that means you have several visits in that day. Add all columns to the PK: `PRIMARY KEY(MRN, VISIT_DATE, visit_id)` that should solve the problem.

Comment: @deroby the PK creates a clustered index implicitly. This is the only index you actually need in that query. Statistics are only good when query engine is selecting indexes to be used, there is no need for that here. Finally table variables have well defined scope. You can rerun this query in the same window in management studio without needing to issue drop table #temp.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to understand the difference between `(...)A` and `(...)B`.
Wouldn't it be more readable to use a correlated subquery like this?
=> IMHO it might even be more efficient as the amount of data to aggregate is going to be smaller. If you can *shortcut* `Plm_Pt_Acct_Type` that would probably make it even a bit faster but I don't have enough info on the tables to know if that would result in the same results .. (probably not I think). There is another possibility to somehow *shortcut* `B.vst_start_dtime`, `@SD`, `B.vst_start_dtime`, `@ED` and `A.vst_start_dtime` in the subquery, but I don't have time to think it through right now =)

PS: having more info on the actual tables (constraints, indexes, rowcount, etc) + a print-screen of the actual execution plan would probably help a lot.

```
;WITH ERCNT AS (SELECT MRN         = MED_REC_NO, 
                       VISIT_ID    = PT_NO,
                       VISIT_DATE  = vst_start_dtime, 
                       VISIT_COUNT = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                         FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V B
                                        WHERE -- can we simply assume B.Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = A.Plm_Pt_Acct_Type ??
                                            ((
                                                B.Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
                                                AND B.Adm_Source NOT IN
                                                    (
                                                    'RP'
                                                    )
                                                )
                                                OR B.pt_type = 'E')
                                          AND B.vst_start_dtime >= @SD 
                                          AND B.vst_start_dtime < @ED
                                          -- 'join'
                                          AND A.MED_REC_NO = B.MED_REC_NO
                                          AND A.PT_NO = B.PT_NO
                                          AND A.vst_start_dtime > B.vst_start_dtime
                                       )

                FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V A
                WHERE
                    ((
                        A.Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
                        AND A.Adm_Source NOT IN 
                            (
                            'RP'
                            )
                        )
                        OR A.pt_type = 'E')
                    AND A.vst_start_dtime >= @SD 
                    AND A.vst_start_dtime < @ED
                )
SELECT * FROM ERCNT
```

Comment: We cannot assume that the plm_pt_acct_types are equal, I need to specify the 'I' because a previous visit could realistically be something else. I will try and post more of the information that would be helpful for you.

Comment: the table itself is a view, I try clicking on the Indexes (+) sign and nothing comes up, so I am sure this will be a limitation

Comment: Well, if it's a view than indexing is a bit more complex (and might have unwanted side-effects), but it still might be worth looking at the definition of the view (use `sp_helptext`) and see if the underlying table(s) have proper indexes. SQL does not really query the view but rather builds its query plan on the underlying tables. Out of curiosity, is the accepted answer really faster than the subquery? (I don't particularly care about the points, just wonder what their execution plans might look like.)

Comment: I was faster, not much, but yes, I have to make certain specifications because I can't assume one visit is always going to be this or that, so I have to specify that each visit looked at must meet these criteria explicitly